# ios jitsi meet completely integrated but having following error

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-application, jitsi-meet

completely deploy exactly same as they deploy but having error

```
load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “doctory.care” which could put your confidential information at risk. 
"UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “doctory.care” which could put your confidential information at risk.} 
[-1202] 2019-02-20 18:10:33.916 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] '[__filename]', '<l>: ', 'Failed to load config from https://doctory.care/config.js?room=dr.qureshi', TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.anonymousdomain') This error is located at:
in t
in l
in Connect(l)
in Connect(Connect(l))
in RCTView
in n
in t
in Connect(t)
in RCTView
in n
in t
in Connect(t)
in o
in u
in h
in n
in RCTView
in RCTView
in c
2019-02-20 18:10:34.787526+0500 Doctory[54578:1100708] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.anonymousdomain')
This error is located at:
in t
in l
in Connect(l)
in Connect(Connect(l))
in RCTView
in n
in t
in Connect(t)
in RCTView
in n
in t
in Connect(t)
in o
in u
in h
in n
in RCTView
in RCTView
in c
```

with this error my simulator shows black screen nothing at all by using my own url of jitsi meet .org but when i use  url to nil it use its default url and app run ok   and fine any help to sort out  the problem

Comment: Do you have “Set Automatically” option turned on? In iOS settings > general > date & time

Comment: no i haven't did it automatically but now i can check it

Comment: no its now working

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using custom Jitsi installation on your own server, Please make sure your SSL certificate is up to date. I was having this issue and renewing the SSL certificate on the server did the trick.